# Why data cleaning decreases accuracy?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics, cross-validation

Using the 20newsgroups from the scikit learn for reproducibility. When I train an svm model and then perform data cleaning  by removing headers, footers and quotes the accuracy decreases. Isn't it supposed to be improved by data cleaning? What is the point in doing all that and then get worse accuracy?

I have created this example with data cleaning to help you understand what I am referring at:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
categories = ['alt.atheism', 'comp.graphics']
newsgroups_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', categories=categories, shuffle=True, random_state=2017, 
                                    remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes')  )
newsgroups_test = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='test', categories=categories,shuffle=True, random_state=2017, 
                                    remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes') )
y_train = newsgroups_train.target
y_test = newsgroups_test.target

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, smooth_idf = True, max_df=0.5,  ngram_range=(1, 2),stop_words='english')
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(newsgroups_train.data)
X_test = vectorizer.transform(newsgroups_test.data)


from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn import metrics

clf = SVC(C=10, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
    decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma=1, kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1,
    probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True, tol=0.001,
    verbose=False)
clf = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_train_pred = clf.predict(X_train)
y_test_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
print('Train accuracy_score: ', metrics.accuracy_score(y_train, y_train_pred))
print('Test accuracy_score: ',metrics.accuracy_score(newsgroups_test.target, y_test_pred))
print("-"*12)
print("Train Metrics: ", metrics.classification_report(y_train, y_train_pred))
print("-"*12)
print("Test Metrics: ", metrics.classification_report(newsgroups_test.target, y_test_pred))
```

Results before data cleaning:

```
Train accuracy_score:  1.0
Test accuracy_score:  0.9731638418079096
```

Results after data cleaning:

```
Train accuracy_score:  0.9887218045112782
Test accuracy_score:  0.9209039548022598
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessarily your data cleaning, I assume you run the script twice?

The problem is this line of code:

```
clf = SVC(C=10, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
    decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma=1, kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1,
    probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True, tol=0.001,
    verbose=False)
```

`random_state=None`You should fix random state to e.g. `random_state=42`, otherwise you cannot produce the same result, if you would run this code again right now, you will again have a different result.

**Edit:**

The explanation is on the [dataset](https://scikit-learn.org/0.19/datasets/twenty_newsgroups.html) site itself:
If you implement:

```
import numpy as np
def show_top10(classifier, vectorizer, categories):
 feature_names = np.asarray(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
 for i, category in enumerate(categories):
   top10 = np.argsort(classifier.coef_[i])[-10:]
   print("%s: %s" % (category, " ".join(feature_names[top10])))
```

You can now see many things that these features have overfit to:

Almost every group is distinguished by whether headers such as NNTP-Posting-Host: and Distribution: appear more or less often.

Another significant feature involves whether the sender is affiliated with a university, as indicated either by their headers or their signature.

The word “article” is a significant feature, based on how often people quote previous posts like this: “In article [article ID], [name] <[e-mail address]> wrote:”

Other features match the names and e-mail addresses of particular people who were posting at the time.

With such an abundance of clues that distinguish newsgroups, the classifiers barely have to identify topics from text at all, and they all perform at the same high level.

For this reason, the functions that load 20 Newsgroups data provide a parameter called remove, telling it what kinds of information to strip out of each file. remove should be a tuple containing any subset of

**Summarize:**

The remove thingy prevents you from data leakage, that means you have information in your training data which you will not have in a prediction phase, so you have to remove it, otherwise you will get a better result, but this will be not there for new data.

Comment: After implementing the suggestion, didn't change anything. Are you getting different results? You can easily run this code in your pc. If you want without the data cleaning simply remove the `remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes')` parts from the train and test variables.

Comment: Thanks, great findings, this is Bunch type. If I upload the dataset as dataframe though how can I do the equivalent of `remove` to remove headers footers, etc?

Comment: when you upload `newsgroup_train`you have it, did not get your question, but if this question is different, it is not in our scope here